# After upgrading to 2.5: Table 'alpineductless-craft.craft_elementindexsettings' doesn't exist

Tags: auto-updates, updating

A client upgraded their site to 2.5, and I believe the update didn't finish.

At first there was a 500 error. I tried rolling the app back (code only) and it  gave an error that the database version didn't support rolling back. Replacing the `craft/app` directory with a fresh version of 2.5 fixed the 500 error.

The site and some of the admin area work, but in the control panel I cannot access Assets or Entries, I get this error:

`CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mysite.craft_elementindexsettings' doesn't exist`

So it seems like something with the migration failed. Except must have not been fully failed, because of the error I got about the database version.

The catch is that the client didn't do a database backup before initiating the update, so there isn't a good rollback point.

Could I manually add this table? Any other potentially fixes for this? Is there a way to tell Craft to re-run the migration to 2.5?

Comment: Unless it's disabled, Craft will [automatically perform a DB backup](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#backupDbOnUpdate) before running an update. Were automatic backups disabled?

Comment: Oh, thank you. I didn't realize this. Importing that backed up database initiated the migration and the problem is fixed. For anyone finding this unfamiliar with where the automatic backup is, it's /craft/storage/backups

Answer (score 3):

As Lindsey D pointed out in the comment, the answer was to restore the database backup from the automatic backup located in `/craft/storage/backups` that is generated when the update was initiated.

When this backup is put into place it will re-run the database migration when you visit the Admin area.

So my full solution was 2 steps:

1. Replace /craft/app with a fresh copy
2. Restore the automatically backed up database in `/craft/storage/backups`